# background image doesn't position at top left

Tags: html, css

I am scratching my head that why I need to put

padding-top: 1px; 
under #pageHeader identifier to get background image at top left set at #container otherwise it displays few pixels below from top.

Even If I put padding-top : 0; it doesn't work.

Moreover it also works if I put it under #intro OR I remove h1 tag inside pageheader div.

My CSS file

```
html 
    {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;             

    }
body 
    { 
        font: 75% georgia, sans-serif;
        line-height: 1.95;
        color: #555753;         
        background: #fff url(../images/bottom.gif) no-repeat bottom right; 
        margin: 0; 
        padding: 0;
    }
#container 
    { 
        background: url(../images/bg.gif) no-repeat left top; 
        padding: 0 175px 0 110px;  
        margin: 0; 
        position: relative;
    }   
#intro 
    { 
        min-width: 470px;
        width: 100%;
    }
#pageHeader 
    {
        padding-top: 1px;   
        height: 87px;
    }
```

My HTML file looks like

```
<div id="container">
<div id="intro">
<div id="pageHeader">
<h1>Hello World!</h1>   
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

**Edit~~**
Its html and body.. actually in my code but I was messed up with editor while pasting here.

Comment: sorry.. its already html and body in my code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The phenomenon you're observing here is called "collapsing margins". The h1 element has a certain margin. This collapses with the margins of the outer divs, so the pageHeader div is shifted down. By setting a non-zero padding to the pageHeader div, you prevent the margins from collapsing.

See the [W3C specs](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/box.html#collapsing-margins), if you read carefully they say:

"Two margins are adjoining if and only if: ... no padding ... separate them"

The rules also say:

"When two or more margins collapse, the resulting margin width is the maximum of the collapsing margins' widths."

So the effect is that your outer divs which have top margins of 0 actually acquire the top margin of the h1 element which is the maximum of all the top margins.

Comment: I understand it now.. If I understand it correctly then margin of h1 is passed through all tags and reaches #container div bypassing #pageheader and #intro then its margin takes effect. And by padding-top in #intro or #pageheader pushes these divs down now h1 cannot reach to #container.. Am I right?

Comment: Yes; by adding the non-zero padding-top you prevent the margin of the h1 from combining with the margin of the outer div, so the margin of the h1 stays within the pageHeader div, and the outer divs keep their zero margins and have their top edge at the page top.

Comment: I tried to search for list of all these kind of conflicting elements and other these kind of odd (apparently) odd characteristics.. but I am not yet successful to find any good resource. Can you please help me to get all info about these kind of behaviors?

Answer (score 1):

You can have all the details of default styling at http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/sample.html